# How to use my variables in file cmake-kits.json?

Tags: json, cmake, vscode-extensions

I am writing extension for VSCode and stumbled upon a problem. I have a file `settings.json`

```
{
    "myVar": "a_directory"
}
```

And file `cmake-kits.json`:

```
{
    "name": "kit",
    "toolchainFile": "${config:myVar}"
     ...
}
```

So a can't use the variable myVar the way I wrote, but in file `launch.json` everything is ok.

I didn't find any helpful information in official VSCode site.